# Docker on Windows not updating files from host

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

Docker on Windows not updating files from host

First of all I should mention I am new to Docker, if there are alternative ways of achieving the same thing, other way of starting the image. I am open to ideas.

Everything works flawlessly on my mac, but not on my windows computer. On the mac I make changes to the files pertaining the app and it livereloads, on Windows I need to stop docker-compose and restart it to have the files updated.
Any ideas? The Volume is shared in the setting of Docker, if not it would not even do anything.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.4
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /site
COPY Gemfile* /site/
WORKDIR /site
RUN bundle install
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  middleman:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4567:4567" #Middleman server default port
      - "1234:1234" #port 1234 is for middleman livereload, config of middleman was changed for this.
    volumes:
      - .:/site
    tty: true
    command: middleman server
```